# UIBarButtonItem losing their custom view image

Tags: iphone

I'm using iphone sdk 3.1.2.

I have 3 root view controllers each on separate tabs. Their left nav bar button has a custom view assigned as follows in each of their `viewDidLoad` methods. The master custom view is held by the `AppDelegate`. Each `regView` is a retained property. In the `appDidFinishlaunching` method I alloc an `imageView` (instance of `AppDelegate`) and assign it an image:

```
UImageView* regView;
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIImageView* regView;

-(void) viewDidLoad
{
 ....

self.regView = appDelegate.regView;

    UIBarButtonItem* regButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.regView];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = regButton;
    [regButton release];
}
```

However when I swap between the tab bar items the previous selected view controller loses its `leftBarButton` custom view until only the very last selected holds onto it.The other 2 can never get their leftbutton custom view back!

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure you cannot share subviews like that across multiple views.

You will have to create three unique instances of that `regView` instead of sharing one instance.

Comment: Hi, thanks but its an image which is a status indicator in  my app 
and allows the user to know whats happening in the app regardless of what view he/she is in. So i need to update it in one place really, how do i do this